# An algebra (of sets) is a sigma algebra iff it is a monotone class

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{A}$ an algebra of sets of $X$. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra iff it is a monotone class.

The fact that a $\sigma$-algebra is a monotone class is trivial; $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable unions and intersections, so it is in particular closed under monotone limits. It is the converse that is troubling me. I would like to assume that any family of sets of $\mathcal{A}$ could be ordered under inclusion. Then this family can be written as an increasing chain of inclusions and the statement follows. But this seems like hand-waving, or simply false (since I do not particularly use the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra). Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: There is good treatment of this on p. 18 of the 3rd edition of Chung's _A Course in Probability Theory_, Theorem 2.1.2. Note that he calls (set) algebras "fields", $\sigma-$algebras "Borel fields", and usually abbreviates monotone class to "M.C". In any case, I really like his chapter 2 on measure theory, and overall Chung's book is one of the best, if not the best, treatments of probability theory at an advanced level.

Comment: @William Thank you, I am currently just preparing myself for a course on integration theory (mostly the Daniell approach) by reading the course summary notes. I have although been looking for a book on modern probability (i.e. Kolmogorov); As you mentioned, Durrett is the overall recommended (course book at my uni). I will certainly give Chung a look!

Comment: Well Durrett is the most popular, I guess because Chung's is a little older. Nevertheless, I have read both and I think Chung's is better for at least three reasons: (1) as a researcher he made very important contributions to probability and his deep understanding of the subject comes through in his book, (2) it gives more detail and explains more of the theory more thoroughly than Durrett, (3) a lot of Durrett's proofs are actually more or less lifted from Chung's book, i.e. Durrett used Chung's book in large part to write his own. If Durrett improved the material is a subjective judgment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to turn any sequence of sets into a monotone increasing or decreasing sequence of sets, you have to use the finite unions/finite intersections (respectively) and set complements.

A set algebra is precisely a collection of sets which is closed under finite unions, finite intersections, and set complements.

Note also that being closed under finite unions and set complements implies being closed under finite intersections, and being closed under finite intersections and  set complements implies being closed under finite unions, by DeMorgan's Laws.

I'm trying to find a source for this, and I can't right now, but I believe if you have a countable union of sets, not necessarily increasing, i.e. $$B = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} B_i$$ then you can always write it as the limit of an increasing union of sets by setting: $$A_1=B_1, A_2= B_1 \cup B_2, \dots, A_n = B_1 \cup \dots \cup B_n $$ Then clearly $\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} B_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$. Since each of the $A_i$ is defined using only a finite union, it is guaranteed to be in the system of sets if that system is a set algebra. Then because it is a monotone class, it contains the union of the $A_i$, thus the union of the $B_i$ which is equal, and therefore it is even a $\sigma-$algebra, since $B_i$ was an arbitrary countable family.

If you want to write in the form $\lim_{i \to \infty} C_i = \emptyset$, then it suffices to write $$C_n = A_n \setminus A_{n-1} $$ and we are only guaranteed that each $C_i$ is in our set system if it is a set algebra because otherwise the set system may not be closed under set complements.

And of course $$\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} B_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} C_i$$

The procedure for showing closure under countable intersections is equivalent; just use the fact that your set system is closed under set complements combined with DeMorgan's Laws.

Comment: Thank you! Makes perfect sense.