# Indicator function, $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of real-valued functions on $X$ such that the constant functions are in $\mathcal{F}$ and $f + g$, $fg$ and $cf$ are in $\mathcal{F}$ whenever $f$, $g \in \mathcal{F}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f \in \mathcal{F}$ whenever $f_n \to f$ and each $f_n \in \mathcal{F}$. Define the function$$\chi_A(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x \in A \\ 0 & \text{if }x \notin A.\end{cases}$$How do I see that $\mathcal{A} = \{A \subset X : \chi_A \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Well, have you tried proving any of the axioms for $\sigma$-algebras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difficult axiom for $\sigma-$algebras to show would be closure under countable unions and intersections. However, this follows  from the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under pointwise limits (i.e. $f_n \in \mathcal{F}\ \forall n \implies \lim f_n = f \in \mathcal{F}$).

To show that this is the case, use the facts that for two sets $A$ and $B$ $A \cup B$ is $\max \{1_A, 1_B  \}$, i.e. $$1_{A \cup B} = \max\{1_A, 1_B \}$$ and $$1_{A \cap B} = \min\{1_A, 1_B\}$$ This can then be extended to finitely many sets, and then the closure under pointwise limits will allow us to show that countable unions and intersection of $A_i$ are included in the collection. It may also be useful to make the sequences of sets monotone first, see e.g. [An algebra (of sets) is a sigma algebra iff it is a monotone class](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880347/an-algebra-of-sets-is-a-sigma-algebra-iff-it-is-a-monotone-class/1880350#1880350)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response! Why do we have $1_{A \cup B} = \max \{1_A, 1_B\}$ and $1_{A \cap B} = \min \{1_A, 1_B\}$? Also, the indicator function above is defined at $x$, so why can we just evaluate it on the whole set as you presumably did? Additionally, how does closure under pointwise limits imply countable unions and intersections are included in the collection?

Comment: As for why those identities with the indicator functions hold, it's a nice exercise -- write out all of the definitions and hopefully you will see it then. If not, then look at the Wikipedia pages for the truth functions of AND and OR. I don't understand what you mean by evaluating on a whole set - the identities are meant to hold pointwise, for example $1_{A\cap B}(x)=\min\{1_A(x), 1_B(x) \}$. As for why the pointwise convergence implies closure under countable unions/intersections, the idea is to write the supremum/infimum of countably many functions as a pointwise limit.

Comment: That might be difficult to show in general, but if you use the trick in the question/answer I linked to, any countable union can be written as the union of monotone increasing sets, hence the corresponding  indicator functions will be monotone increasing, so the supremum of the indicator functions will be their limit, and we have by assumption that the functions are closed under pointwise limits. Similarly for countable intersections Good questions; let me know if you have more. Also note/remember that the supremum and infimum coincide with the maximum respectively the minimum for finite sets